# AWS Elasticsearch: closing index for putSettings 'is not allowed'?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, config

I have one issue. My Elasticsearch index should have Email analyzer for storing emails in the right way. For the reason, I created new analyzer in config and call method `client.indices.putSettings` (Node.js). But official documentation said that firstly we need to call `_close` method for our index and after that we should call `putSettings`.

When I worked with Docker image this methods executed without any problems. But on AWS I got the following exception:

```
Your request: '/index/_close' is not allowed by Amazon Elasticsearch Service.
```

How can I set my custom settings to Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

Answer (score 0):

Your original title was 'how do I put settings on ElasticSearch' but the body of your question is asking about a specific error.

Answering the original title, **AWS Elasticsearch Service: How to put settings?**

[The node.js documentation for ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.x/api-reference.html#_indices_putsettings) covers `putSettings()`

```js
client.indices.putSettings({
  index: string | string[],
  master_timeout: string,
  timeout: string,
  preserve_existing: boolean,
  ignore_unavailable: boolean,
  allow_no_indices: boolean,
  expand_wildcards: 'open' | 'closed' | 'none' | 'all',
  flat_settings: boolean,
  body: object
})
```

`body` is defined in the [general HTTP API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.x/api-reference.html#_indices_putsettings)